# collect data from usb mouse macintosh os x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, usb

I would like to collect the data from my usb mouse with my OS X Sierra, with javascript / angular js.
Any idea where I can find the inputs ?

I would like to get the bits packets. Precisely, I would like then to calculate position, speed ect... of the cursor.

Comment: What is "the data" that you are trying to collect? Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to get the bits packets.
Precisely, I would like then to calculate position, speed ect... of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp (seriously, this SHOULD have everything you need), you can create a function that calculates the current mouse position and speed.

The event you may have been looking for would be onmousemove. Try giving the window object that property. Your function should be called with an event object too which contains clientX and clientY data, use that to track the current position of the mouse.

Of course, to calculate the mouse speed, we just need to know the difference between the last position it was in, and the current position. So this should work:

```
var Mx = 0; // Mouse X position
var My = 0; // Mouse Y position
var lastSpeedx = 0; // Last movement by mouse on x axis
var lastSpeedy = 0; // Last movement by mouse on y axis
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    lastSpeedx = e.clientX - Mx; lastSpeedy = e.clientY - My;
    Mx = e.clientX; My = e.clientY;
}
```

Although I hear you want to hear exactly what comes through that usb port, well I'm afraid it's not exactly that simple. Even if javascript has some kind of extension that might do that, it won't be fun to deal with the hundreds of different interfaces mice use to talk to your computer. Drivers are somewhat there to simplify this, then the OS simplifies it further, and by the time it gets to your javascript parser, it would have be quite basic.

I actually to accomplish low level usb input on C++ a couple years back (just for fun) but I just couldn't find what I needed.

I'll look into a direct solution for you, along with an angularjs solution (because I wrote this answer before I saw angularjs tagged), although I'm not sure if there's one as low level as you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually I would like to get the bits packets. Precisely, I would like then to calculate position, speed ect... of the cursor. Any clues ?

Comment: Oh. You can get the position of the cursor with javascript and the movement of the cursor with some variables. I'll redo my answer, but I don't think you'll be able to access exactly what's coming from your usb port unless you use some kind of super low level implementation of javascript. I'll look into it though. Are you programming for a javascript browser? If so which one. Otherwise, what implementation are you using (or what are you using to run your programs)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good beginning for me. It is actually a desktop application.
What I really want is the packets coming from the usb. The bits !
So it is not a browser. To run my program I use electron.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some looking into it. By the way, what do you mean by "bits"?

Comment: Hey, does the https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb library meet your needs?

Comment: Hi @Frzn,
Thank you for your answer.
I meant the packets of bytes of hexadecimals. 
Will try your package. Keep you followed up.